# Copy macro to newly generated workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

Right, so I hit a bit of a wall here. I have this nice piece of code which works really well for file security.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
 Dim wsh As Worksheet
 Dim rng As Range
 On Error Resume Next
 For Each wsh In Me.Worksheets
    wsh.Unprotect Password:="x"
    wsh.Cells.Locked = False
    Set rng = wsh.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        rng.Locked = True
    End If
    Set rng = wsh.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        rng.Locked = True
    End If
    wsh.Protect Password:="x"
 Next wsh
End Sub
```

But I want to add it to new files. Every week a few new files get generated but they need to be protected as well. And it's a hassle to have to do it by hand.

I tried saving the macro to my personal macro's. But that doesn't work. Even if I make it a normal macro instead of 'on open'.

What would work, I think is whenever I open a newly generated workbook, a macro runs that copies the security code to the new workbook. But I am clueless on how to do that, seeing as the name also changes every time.

So... ideas?

Comment: Possibly useful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.workbookopen and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/events-worksheetfunctions-shapes/using-events-with-the-application-object

Comment: A few options, such as application level events http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/AppEvent.aspx. Or perhaps an add-in, depending on whether you actually need the code in the workbooks?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, figured it out thanks to SJR.

I edited the code a bit to be

```
Sub Security()
 Dim wsh As Worksheet
 Dim rng As Range
 On Error Resume Next
 For Each wsh In Worksheets
    wsh.Unprotect Password:="x"
wsh.Cells.Locked = False
Set rng = wsh.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    rng.Locked = True
End If
Set rng = wsh.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    rng.Locked = True
End If
wsh.Protect Password:="x"
 Next wsh
End Sub
```

And made it into an add-in.
And as a unexpected, but most welcome surprise, it now also works in non-macro enabled workbooks, Yay!

So when a new file is generated, I just open it to check it and then press 1 button on the ribbon to secure it.

Thank you!